# environment variable not working in react firebase config file

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, environment-variables

I am making a react app with firebase and I want to use environment variables for the firebase config.
this is the firebase config in my react apps src folder

```js
import firebase from "firebase"
import "firebase/auth"

console.log(process.env)

const config = {
    //private stuff
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.analytics();

export default firebase
```

the issue is with that console log, I am using that for debugging, it is logging

```
NODE_ENV: "production"
PUBLIC_URL: ""
WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined
WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined
WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined
```

when it should be logging

```
NODE_ENV: "production"
PUBLIC_URL: ""
WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined
WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined
WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined
GOOGLE_API_KEY: "key"
```

why aren't my custom environment variables showing up? I am using AWS amplify for deployment so that is what would be providing the environment variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Your project can consume variables declared in your environment as if
they were declared locally in your JS files. By default you will have
`NODE_ENV` defined for you, and any other environment variables starting
with `REACT_APP_`.

> Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with
>   `REACT_APP_`. Any other variables except `NODE_ENV` will be ignored to
>   avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could
>   have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require
>   you to restart the development server if it is running.

Answer (score 2):

1. create .env file in your root where package.json located.
2. make variable name with REACT_APP_customName/cofigString
3. replace the values with the variable (2)
4. save both files
5. check the project

Answer (score 0):

** Make sure your .env file is in the root directory, not inside src folder.